# How to convert VBA Macro code to run with VBScript

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I have the following VBA/Macro code:

```
Sub MergeSameCells()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim rng As Range

MergeCells:

For Each rng In Selection
    If rng.Value = rng.Offset(1, 0).Value And rng.Value <> "" Then
        Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
        Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Range(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        GoTo MergeCells
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Problem: Everytime I get a new s/s file with duplicate rows, I have to copy the code above and create macro. I do not want to do this. Instead, I first hoped if there was a way to convert a macro to an "EXE" file and apparently, I cannot do that. So, the next best option that Google recommended was to use VBScript. So, this is what I coded:

```
dim XlApp
dim wb
dim ws
dim objRange
dim rng
set XlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
XlApp.Visible = True
Path = "C:\Users\zkumh45\Documents\Bundling Sizing 20191025.xlsx"
set wb = XlApp.Workbooks.Open(path)
set ws = wb.Sheets("export (23)")
Set objRange = XlApp.Range("A2","A5")  

For Each rng In objRange
    If rng.Value = objRange.Offset(1, 0).Value And rng.Value <> "" Then
        objRange(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
        objRange(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        objRange(rng, rng.Offset(1, 0)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter       
    End If
Next 
wb.close
```

I know my vbs code is flawed (cuz it keeps erroring out) but I was trying to get some basic code running but I am out of wits. Can anyone help with this code?

Here is the error that I am encountering:

[image]

Comment: Just add the code to a personal workbook or addin and skip the VBScript entirely?

Comment: It's not particularly helpful to tell us that your VBS code "keeps erroring out" but not tell us which line or what the error is.  Also, it took me a few seconds to figure out what "s/s" means.  Why not make it easy for us to help you?

Comment: @Marc - haha, sincere apologies. Point duly note about "s/s". Being a Project manager and putting a coder hat is not easy after all. I have added a snippet to show the error code and line.

Comment: @BigBen - I will google what it means by "Add code to personal workbook". I have come across this suggestion while I looking for an answer but overlooked it because I thought that was not relevant to my issue.

Comment: @BigBen - Yeap, that worked. I copied the whole code into a module under Personal Workbook and now, I am able to see that macro in any spreadsheet I open. Awesome, bud. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For those who needs help with creating macros in Personal Workbook, see here: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/935101-need-help-i-made-macro-sheet-all-my-vba-codes-i-then-open-sheet-up-book1-add-commands.html